# using print to follow python code

Tags: python, function, printing

i am having some trouble trying to follow the code in on-line learning but no response so i figured i'd google and ask here. what i am trying to accomplish is to print each counter and total for the loop to see and follow the logic: please let me know where i can type print total to see the loop in action.

```
shopping_list = ["banana", "orange", "apple"]

stock = { "banana": 6,
    "apple": 0,
    "orange": 32,
    "pear": 15
}

prices = { "banana": 4,
    "apple": 2,
    "orange": 1.5,
    "pear": 3
}

# Write your code below!
def compute_bill(food):
    total = 0
    for x in food:
        total+=prices[x]
    return total
```

Comment: wow, that was a ridiculously fast edit... i tried putting 'print total' before 'return total' but that didn't work. i tried printing it as a string, but i guess i need help figuring out how to print something within a function.

Comment: i would like to follow the total as the loop progresses, as well as x.  when i print total outside of the function total has not been defined so it doesn't work. when i tried putting total= 0 outside of the function i received an error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can put it right after the `for` expression:

```
 for x in food:
   total += prices[x]
   print(total)
```

make sure your `print` call is intended the same number of spaces as the `total +=` as indentation is important in python.

Comment: thank you. i did this before and it said my total was too high. guess it's a limitation within the gui they provide. curious to see what numbers they were throwing but this definitely helps!

Comment: @SYSzero what you mean the numbers were too high? Perhaps `food` is longer than it should be? Maybe whatever is handing you that iterable has a bug in it.

Answer (score 0):

sorry guys, silly question.

reason why it wasn't printing anything was because i never called the function.

after typing `print compute_bill(shopping_list)` it worked!